# cmake error while catkin_make in catkin_ws?

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, ros, catkin, cmakelists-options

I have updated cmake and when i run catkin_make into the catkin_ws i got error in cmake even if got sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade successful.

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

Below error is shown Cmake Error, cmake_check_build_system' failed.

```
Base path: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/noetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/noetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Forcing gtest/gmock from source, though one was otherwise available.
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.8.10") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests3
-- catkin 0.8.10
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    code = generate_environment_script('/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/env.sh')
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin/environment_cache.py", line 63, in generate_environment_script
    env_after = ast.literal_eval(output.decode('utf8'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 59, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    ROS_DISTRO was set to 'foxy' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:208 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:58 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:3890: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I couldn't solve? How can solve it?

Comment: Hi, Can you share your env |grep ROS command output.

Comment: `ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/share
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS_DISTRO=foxy
`

Comment: Can you run this command, export ROS_DISTRO=noetic and try again.

Comment: It doesn't worked. i have updated the cmake 3.16.3 and i got error after that only. i don't know whether it affects or not?

Comment: Looks like you’re mixing ros versions. What does your CMakeLists.txt file look like? And have you installed any packages from source? i.e. cloned from a git repo?

Comment: what's the point of the screenshot if you also show it as text?

Comment: I have cloned all the packages from git and i have both ros1(noetic) and ros2(foxy). should i have either one of this?  my CMakeLists.txt file looks like `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)`

Comment: @SuganS no, you shouldn’t. You’re missing ROS versions which isn’t valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment you’re mixing ROS versions in your workspace. This isn’t valid *in the same worksapce*. You might have a system that uses both, but they should be built within different contexts; i.e. a directory shouldn’t contain both. It also should be noted that catkin isn’t the build system for ROS2(colcon is).

Comment: Thankyou it works fine with ROS1 alone.

Answer (score 0):

you have `ROS_VERSION=2` and `ROS_DISTRO=foxy`, however, the rest refers to `noetic`. Try doing `export ROS_VERSION=1` and `export ROS_DISTRO=noetic`.

I don't know how you are sourcing your workspace, but if you have that in your `bashrc`, I suggest removing it and sourcing it manually.